# Different Logo for Different Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to show a different logo for page ID 1111 with code snippet below. But it is showing both logos on every page. Not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. This snippet is in my header.php theme file Wordpress.

```html
<a title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo esc_url($log_url); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>"  width="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 0); ?>" height="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 1); ?>" >
 <?php if (is_page( 1111 )) ?>
 <img src="https://teamambrose.realtor/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/favicon.ico.png" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>"  width="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 0); ?>" height="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 1); ?>" >

</a>
```

This is what I added to above hoping to only show second image url on page 1111 only.

```html
<?php if (is_page( 1111 )) ?>
<img src="https://teamambrose.realtor/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/favicon.ico.png" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>"  width="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 0); ?>" height="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 1); ?>" >
```

Comment: `is_page( 1111 )` is literally asking the WordPress engine, "Is the ID `1111` assigned to a page object?" Since, in your environment it is, this condition will always return `true`. Instead, build an `if` statement that asks the WordPress engine if the *current* page corresponds to page ID `1111`.

Comment: Hi esqew, Thank you for responding. Kind of get what your saying but above my code language abilities. If you could fill in the needed code would be super appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why both logos are being shown on every page is because you specified an if-condition but did nothing before you closed the php tag.

Therefore, your extra logo html is being treated as if you added an additional line of HTML code which results in it being shown as any other regular HTML element you have added.

You should add a `:` behind the if statement to indicate that the line after the if statement is grouped under that particular if statement.

E.g.

```
<?php if ( is_page ( 1111 ) ) : ?>
<!-- This will only be printed when page id is 1111. -->
<? endif; ?>
```

You will also have to make sure to end the if statement or all of the code below the if statement will be processed with that if condition.

If what you want to achieve is to show logo A on pages other than 1111 page and only show logo B on page 1111, this is what you should do.

```
<a title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>">
    <?php if ( is_page( 1111 ) ) : ?>
    <img src="https://teamambrose.realtor/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/favicon.ico.png" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>"  width="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 0); ?>" height="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 1); ?>" >
    <?php else : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($log_url); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>"  width="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 0); ?>" height="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 1); ?>" >
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you josephting. That worked perfectly. And I see now what I was missing.

Comment: @Joe Happy to help.